# custom classes integration laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently learning laravel for a small community based website project. I have the necessity to include some custom code/classes in the laravel code. I'll write some custom code that will call some remote api and the JSON response will be converted into some laravel' models and inserted into the database. I would know the right approach to do this in the "laravel 5.5 way" and what components of the framework I should use. Thanks!

Comment: components of the framework to do what? this is rather vague, do you have any code at the moment?  thanks

Comment: Head over to Laracasts, get yourself an account and then: watch and learn.

Answer (score 1):

It's awesome you are learning Laravel, you will find that you will be able to do so much with it.

You could achieve that by good old php in a controller (in app/Http/Controllers/) and save it from there in the database

A good place to start is laracasts.com as the instructor Jeffery Way takes you from zero to hero in no time.
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Have fun.